# Javascript Calling object methods within same object not working well

Tags: javascript

In This `theme` object i have created 2 properties.

**I placed `this.changeThemeTo(1);` under the Event Listener, after that it worked. But i want to place it within `if` tag**

*But seems giving an error when put it within `if`*

> Uncaught TypeError: **this.changeThemeTo** is not a function

***please help to fix this. Thanks..***

```
var theme = {
    changeThemeTo: function (theme_value) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('THEME'); // remove old theme from session storage
        if (theme_value == 0) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("THEME", 'dark');
        } else if (theme_value == 1) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("THEME", 'light');
        }
        document.body.className = sessionStorage.getItem("THEME");
    },
    init: function () {
        document.body.classList.add("fade");
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.classList.remove("fade");
        }, 100);

        var themes = ['dark', 'light'];

        themes.forEach(function (item) {
            var button = document.querySelector("." + item);

            if (button) {
                button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (item == "dark") {
                        this.changeThemeTo(0);
                    } else if (item == "light") {
                        this.changeThemeTo(1);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, this);
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    theme.init();
}
```

**Here my html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .dark {
    background-color: #191919;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
.light {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #191919;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="change-theme">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dark">DARK</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="light">LIGHT</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `theme` instead of `this`.

Comment: I agree with @MinusFour because the problem is that likely the `this` object is pointing to the `button` variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `self.changeThemeTo` instead `this.changeThemeTo`. and define self = this as per the below code sample. also optimized some portion of the code.

```js
var theme = {
    changeThemeTo: function (theme_value) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("THEME", theme_value);
        document.body.className = theme_value;
    },
    init: function () {
        document.body.classList.add("fade");
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.classList.remove("fade");
        }, 100);

        var themes = ['dark', 'light'];
        var self = this;

        themes.forEach(function (item) {
            var button = document.querySelector("." + item);

            if (button) {
                button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                     self.changeThemeTo(item);
                });
            }
        }, this);
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    theme.init();
}
```

```html
 <style type="text/css">
    .dark {
    background-color: #191919;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
.light {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #191919;
}
</style>
<div id="change-theme">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dark">DARK</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="light">LIGHT</a>
</div>
```